# «Грамота» или Грамота?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, кавычки, названия

Как правильно?

`Я иногда даже не знаю, кому верить – Лопатину, Розенталю или Грамоте.`

`Я иногда даже не знаю, кому верить – Лопатину, Розенталю или «Грамоте».`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Названия и веб-адреса сайтов**](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1_%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2/):

> При написании названий сайтов действуют общие правила: названия пишутся с прописной буквы и заключаются в кавычки: *порталы «Яндекс», «Рамблер», «Культура письменной речи»; социальные сети «Фейсбук», «ВКонтакте»* (официальное название этого ресурса именно такое, хотя оно противоречит нормам русского письма; должно быть: *«В контакте»*, ср.: *журнал «За рулем», не «ЗаРулем»*).
>
> Компонент после точки (если он присутствует в названии) пишется строчными: ***«Грамота.ру»*** (см.: Лопатин В. В., Нечаева И. В., Чельцова Л. К. Прописная или строчная? Орфографический словарь. М., 2011).
>
> Полагаем, что в бытовом употреблении (при передаче на письме разговорной речи) допустимо написание строчными без кавычек: *пост в фейсбуке, проверить слово на **грамоте**, рекламная ссылка из гугла, фото в инстаграме* (здесь возможна аналогия с пунктами правил, описывающими бытовое употребление названий торговых марок, изделий и товаров).

Сама Грамота, например, пишет: «Корректно: *портал «Грамота.ру», но сайт Google, компания Google, платформа Moodle».*

Но всё зависит от того, **где** и **кому** мы пишем. От стиля, от "официоза", от экзамена, от используемой площадки со своими негласно принятыми правилами.
**Пишите так, чтобы вас поняли.** На этом сайте привычно написание без кавычек, но с большой буквы (чтобы обозначить имя ресурса и, если хотите, проявить уважение). Для новичков, которые, может быть, ни разу не сталкивались с этим порталом, лучше оформить чётко: *на сайте «Грамота.ру»*. А в переписке, в комментариях можно не церемониться: *на грамоте*. Если название оформлено в гиперссылке, то кавычки, мне кажется, уже излишни.

Так что возможны разные варианты:
gramota.ru
«Грамота.ру»
Грамота.ру
«Грамота»
Грамота
[ГРАМОТА.РУ](http://gramota.ru/): «При полном или частичном использовании материалов ссылка на ГРАМОТУ.РУ обязательна».

Курсив ещё в придачу...

Comment: Блеск!  Просто справочник по теме!  Я начинаю с бОльшим уважением относиться к теме оформления.

Comment: @Sharon Угу, спасибо!